# java.util.NoSuchElementException Error?

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I'm a beginner Java programmer, and I was trying to make a program that would allow the user to make a Fruit object by entering a name, quantity and mass. I made a seperate fruit class with a constructor. When I ask the user to input the name, everything is fine but when it gets to the quantity/mass I get a java.util.NoSuchElementException runtime error.

This is my code

```
public class Fruit {

    String Name;
    int Quantity;
    double Mass;

    public Fruit (String Name, int Quantity, double Mass){
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Quantity = Quantity;
        this.Mass = Mass;
    }

    public void Information(){
        System.out.println("This fruit is an " + Name + " and there's " + Quantity + " of it");
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fruits {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        Fruit Apple = new Fruit("Apple", 5, 32.6);
        System.out.println (Apple.Name);

            System.out.println("What would you like to name the fruit?: ");
            Scanner name1 = new Scanner (System.in);
            String name = name1.nextLine();
            name1.close();

            System.out.println("How much fruits are there?: ");
            Scanner quant1 = new Scanner (System.in);
            int quantity = quant1.nextInt();
            quant1.close();

            System.out.println("What is the mass of the Fruit?: ");
            Scanner mass1 = new Scanner (System.in);
            double mass = mass1.nextDouble();
            mass1.close();

            Fruit newFruit = new Fruit (name, quantity, mass);

            newFruit.Information();

    }
}
```

Comment: When you close the scanner, you also close the underlying `System.in` stream. Use only one Scanner instance, and close it once you finished to give all your inputs.

Comment: Also, to follow Java coding standards, your variables should be lowercase. (`Name` should be `name`, `Quantity` should be `quantity`, etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need create multiple scanner objects. When you closing your first scanner actually you are closing `System.in`. So second element can't get System.in. So it is better to use Single scanner for all input retrieval

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("What would you like to name the fruit?: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How much fruits are there?: ");
        int quantity = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("What is the mass of the Fruit?: ");
        double mass = scanner.nextDouble();
```